# Another typical 403 Forbidden error for new website in apache

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

today I've added a new website on server which runs Apache 2.4 (all sites being added before Apache 2.4 are working with the old directives). This new site gets the 403 error, I tried to change the directives from "Require all granted" to "Order allow,deny
Allow from all" which works for all other sites on server but still not working.
Directives for new site (not working): http://pastebin.com/smJQNbxn
Directives for old sites (working): http://pastebin.com/M7nbMsJe

Comment: Please include the code directly in the question, do not refer to some arbitrary external site. This is clearly explained in the "how to ask questions here" section. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to do it but code is too big with so many spaces that editor doesn't let me post it...

Comment: Obviously I only referred to the relevant parts of code.